# How to get variables out of a block in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I have the following code:

```
__block NSDictionary *results;

if (username.length != 0 && password.length != 0) {
    NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"login", @"command",
                                  username, @"username",
                                  password, @"password",
                                  nil];

    [[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        for (id key in json) {

            NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [json objectForKey:key]);
        }

        results = json;
    }];
}
for (id key in results) {

    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [results objectForKey:key]);

}
```

This some code from a tutorial that I'm trying to play with to figure some things out.  In the tutorial, there was a lot of code done in the 'on completion' part and I'd like to just have it return the NSDictionary so the calling code can handle the result itself.

The problem I'm having is that results is not being set.  The first NSLog for loop prints output but the 2nd one does not.  What am I missing?

Comment: If the block is running asynchronously then you will not have results until after completion. If you put a breakpoint on your `results = json;` and another breakpoint on your `NSLog` you will see the `NSLog` getting called before `results` get set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing understaning of asynch operations. The completion block is not invoked until the operation which you initiated has been completed. However, the NSLog statement is executed immediately after the message send to `[API sharedInstance]` - and `results` is nil then.

Comment: Hmmm that makes sense. So blocks are asynch?  Is there a way to make it wait for block completion?  Should i not use blocks?

Comment: @DanBrooking No, not blocks themselves are async. That particular method that invokes your completion block is async. Solution: move the NSLog inside the block.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize the onCompletion was async.  That answers a lot of questions...

Comment: @DanBrooking you're welcome. See, that's just a bit of common sense.  If it wasn't async, the purpose/existence of the completion callback wouldn't be valid, right? :-)

Comment: Yeah it is... I still don't fully understand the concept/point of blocks - hence the messing around with the code like this.  I find the easiest way to learn is find a tutorial, break the code, then dig around and ask questions :)

Comment: @DanBrooking the point is that they're unnamed functions. You don't have to mess with creating a stub class/method/function for a one-time quick callback, just write a block and fire the code straight away!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a completion handler indicates an asynchronous request.  In that case, the code in the `commandWithParams:onCompletion:` method will not have yet run when the code after it executes.

So, you are looking at the results object, but the completion handler has not yet run to set its value, so it's still nil.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that your `commandWithParams:onCompletion:` method is asynchronous. That is, it is dispatched onto another thread.

I'll assume this is a network call since this is what it looks like, but this applies to any async method. Basically it's downloading your data in the background so that you don't freeze up the app.

So what does this mean for your code? Well, you create an uninitialized pointer to an NSDictionary. Then you ask your API class's shared instance to dispatch a network request for you. Then *immediately* after the request is dispatched, most likely before the network request/long running process finishes, the next line of code is executed which happens to be your for loop.